# Using Jquery document.on() on elements that are pulled in via .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm learning how to use delegated events. I have a select box that loads files into a div using `.load` method. Please take a look at this [example](http://painfulmouth.com/test/Testoption.php). One of the files (the content slider) contains javascript that won't work unless I use an delegated event. But the one I'm using doesn't seem to be the right because when I click on the select box below the slider `.select_title`, the buttons above the slider are gone. Can you tell me what delegated event should I use?

I don't think this one is right:

```
$(document).on("mousedown",".selectboxarea", function(){
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var area = $(".selectboxarea");
    $("select").on('change', function () {
        area.toggleClass('red',area.hasClass('white')).empty();
        var $this = $(this);
        var selected = $this.find('option:selected');
        var loadfile = selected.data('file');
        var selectfirst = $('.selectempty');
        var nextarea = $this.next('.selectboxarea');
        $(".searchselectbox").not(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);
        selectfirst.text('Select');
        var hide =         $this.find('.selectempty').text('Hide');$this.find('.selectempty').toggleClass('hide'); 
        if (loadfile) {nextarea.load(loadfile);hide }
    });
});
$(document).on("mousedown",".selectboxarea", function(){
    $('.select_title').change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('.eventslide').hide();
        $('.'+selected.val()).show(); 
    });
    var W = $('#event_rotator').width(),
        N = $('#searchslider .event').length,
        C = 0,
        intv;
    if(N<=1)$('#left, #right').hide(); 
    $('#searchslider').width( W*N );
});
```

Comment: It should look like the second event handler in your code ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, this event handler seems to make the buttons gone. `$(document).on("mousedown",".selectboxarea", function(){`